# Using design patterns to add functionality at runtime

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have an abstract class "MainClass" which composes "Animal" class. I derive two classes TypeA and TypeB from abstract class which contains common functionality. TypeA and TypeB classes need to be extended to include their own specific functionality.

For example, TypeA would require to add cat functionality under Animal class. So that test application will be accessing the cat class like this typeA._animals._cat?

I know types cannot be added at runtime but is there any other design pattern that could solve my problem?

```
public abstract class MainClass
{
    public Animal _animals;
}

public class Animal
{
    public Tiger _tiger;
}

public class Tiger
{
    public int type { get { return "Tiger" ; } }
}

public class Cat
{
    public int type { get { return "Car" ; } }
}

public class Leopard
{
     public int type { get { return "Leopard" ; } }
}

public class TypeA : MainSession
{
    //Would like to add type Cat to Animal class
}

public class TypeB : MainSession
{
    //Would like to add type Leopard to Animal class  
}
```

Comment: No need to use tags in your title.

Comment: what classes are TypeA and TypeB? Creating Animal class as an abstract class and inheriting Tiger, Cat, Leopard from it wont do better?

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are trying to solve? Your current class structure does not make sense to me

Comment: @BrokenGlass - I want to add types to existing type at run time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you should do is to create an inheritance:

```
public interface IAnimal
{
    string SpeciesName {get; }
}
```

And implement it:

```
public class Tiger : IAnimal
{
    public string SpeciesName { get { return "Tiger" ; } }
}


public class Cat : IAnimal
{
    public string SpeciesName { get { return "Cat" ; } }
}
```

Let's use it:

```
public abstract class MainSession
{
    private List<IAnimal> _animals;

    public IEnumerable<IAnimal> Animals {get { return _animals; }}

    proteced void AddAnimal(IAnimal animal)
    {
        _animals.Add(animal);
    }
}

public class TypeA : MainSession
{
    public TypeA()
    {
        AddAnimal(new Tiger());
    }
}

public class TypeB : MainSession
{
    public TypeB()
    {
        AddAnimal(new Leopard());
    }
}
```

You could also convert the `AddAnimal` into a factory method:

```
public abstract class MainSession
{
    private List<IAnimal> _animals;

    public IEnumerable<IAnimal> Animals {get { return _animals; }}

    protected IAnimal CreateAnimal(string speciesName)
    {
        // Either use reflection to find the correct species,
        // or a simple switch like below:
        switch (speciesName)
        {
            case "tiger":
                return new Tiger();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Having the factory in `MainSession` breaks Single Responsibility Principle, so I would break it out into a separate class.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I believe that Tiger, Cat, Leopard should be inheriting from Animal. Now, you may use a generic base class with type constraints to do the same. For example,

```
public abstract class MainClass<A> where A:Animal
{
    public A _animals;
}

public abstract class Animal
{
    ...
}

public class Tiger : Animal
{
    ...
}

public class Cat : Animal
{
    ...
}

public class Leopard : Animal
{
    ...
}

public class TypeA : MainSession<Cat>
{
    ...
}

public class TypeB : MainSession<Leopard>
{
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Using Abstract Factory Pattern can solve your problem. Check this out on :

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern

Comment: Am not sure how abstract factory can help me here. can you please explain further?

Comment: jgauffin's answer's second part gives one example to use factory.

Answer (score 0):

Your main class needs to have a `List<Animal> _animals` instead of `Animal _animals`.  The Tiger, Cat, and Leopard classes should inherit from the Animal class.  You can then put the `type` property in the `Animal` base class.  At runtime you can add as many `Animals` to the `_animals` list as you would like, and since the `type` property is in the `Animal` base class you will have access to it in all derived classes.

Comment: I thought of maintaining a list but I guess I will have to iterate the list to access a type. I would want to access using the type's name.

Comment: You can use a Dictionary instead of a list and use the type as the key and the Animal object as the value.